# Javascript image warning does not work

Tags: javascript, image, warnings

I try to show image warning message if username or password is empty.

However
if my username or password is empty, image does not appear. Where I miss?

My Javascript code

```
function LoginButonOnclick() {
var data= {
UserName: $('#UserNameTextBox').val(),
Password: $('#PasswordTextBox').val(),
};
if (data.UserName== null) {
$("#showwarning").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png">');
}
if (data.Password== null) {
$("#showwarning").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png" />');
}
}
```

My Html code:

```
<input type="text" id="UsernameTextBox" name="UsernameTextBox"/>
<input type="text" id="PasswordTextBox" name="PasswordTextBox"/>
<input type="button" onclick="LoginButonOnclick()" value="Enter"/>

<div id="showwarning"></div>
```

Comment: Try this `data.UserName==""`
  If this will not work. Just post the warning/error in **inspect element**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 data.UserName=="" //an empty string is not null
```

Comment: Hi rps , ı would like to learn , how can ı set visible true or false for my image ?

Comment: `$("#showwarning").show(), $("#showwarning").hide()` you can ofcourse change the css visiblity using `$("#showwarning img").css({'visibility':'visible'}) , $("#showwarning img").css({'visibility':'hidden'})`  too

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole bunch of trouble.  Here is my updated code:

1. In the HTML The UserName text box was called `UserNameTextBox`, but in the jQuery you named it `UsernameTextBox`.  JavaScript is case sensitive.
2. You can't use `~` for client side paths for images, that's an ASP.Net thing.
3. In JavaScript you can have **falsey** and **truthy** values.  When I check the results, I check for blank and undefined.  Though maybe it would be best to use a regular expression to check for a blank string.

### Code

```
function LoginButonOnclick() {
    var data = {
        UserName: $('#UsernameTextBox').val(),
        Password: $('#PasswordTextBox').val(),
    };

    if (!data.UserName) {
        alert('ERROR!');
        $("#showwarning").html('<img src="/Image/warning.png">');
    }
    if (!data.Password) {
        $("#showwarning").html('<img src="/Image/warning.png" />');
    }
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3C4u/)

Using a regular expression to validate the existence of a non-blank character in a string:

```
if (!/\S/.test(UserName)) {
    $("#showwarning").html('<img src="/Image/warning.png">');
}
```

Comment: This is a complete solution. With fiddle and explanation. Good job

Comment: @user2791307, without any disrespect to rps, my opinion is that this should be marked as the answer as Daniel pointed out multiple issues and solved them for you

Answer (score 1):

You also should take jQuerys

```
bind
```

function to assign the click on the button to a function. See http://jsfiddle.net/jX3N2/